# Grails datepicker looses setting

Tags: grails, pagination

I've noticed that **datepicker** is reset to default value after the request has been done and the page reloaded.

Although I ensured that parameters are saved for use in pagination

```
...
                    <g:paginate total="${totalCount}" id="${params.id}"
                                params="[
                                         startDate      : params.startDate,
                                         startDate_year : params.startDate_year,
                                         startDate_month: params.startDate_month,
                                         startDate_day  : params.startDate_day]
    />
...
```

and it works as expected, the UI component itself shows default value. I'm afraid that it may irritate users. What should be done to make datepicker display the last value set by user and not the default one?

Comment: I'd have thought the params in the paginate will only be submitted if the pagination links are clicked, if you're user is completing the action by some other means they won't be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<g:paginate>` tag is using the params appropriately, but your `<g:datePicker>` tag likely does not use a `value` attribute set to whatever was submitted.

Comment: I've tried it with value='${params.startDate}', but it caused an exception. I don't remember the details as I have no access to the PC at the moment. But I remember that there was some conversion problem. It looked like the framework tried to convert a string which is the type of params.startDate to a Date. I can provide details tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds good.  It probably did try to convert it to a date; you can always use a java.text.DateFormat for that if you need to.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. Your answer pointed me in the right direction but I don't think it's detailed enough especially for those like me who have been using Grails since 2 days. I can either post the code in the comment and you'll add it to your answer or I'll create a new answer.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix the issue.  Without an example of your datePicker code, I did not feel like I could add any more details, but you are more than welcome to either edit my answer or post your own; whichever you feel is most appropriate!  Good luck with the continued grails development!